# Should i buy a GPU without fan?

Tags: graphics-cards

I was surfing through facebook marketplace and i stumbled upon a good GPU (for what i have) very cheap, but with a small tiny detail, **it doesn't have a fan**, although it doesn't appear to be missing the heatsink, the owner claims that the fan broke, and that it didn't affect the GPU, which they also claim that it **works perfectly**.

I currently have an **HD 6570 1gb**, and the GPU in question is the **HD 7850 2GB**, listed at **$15**.
So even without fan if I undervolt it and underclock it a bunch and add it a crappy fan blowing some air to it it should be still 3 or 4x faster than what i already have.

I was just wondering if there's something I should take on count if i'm going to make the move, like the GPU itself not being able to **be undervolted** or the GPU being so hot it needs a **good fan** no matter what or something like that.

And also, the compatibility would actually be really useful since the current gpu I have doesn't support hardware accel on most stuff, specially obs, and NimeZ modded drivers add even more of that to it.
The compatibility is something i want too since some games i want to play **crash a bunch** or **don't even launch**.

btw, im from Argentina so the $15 i'm talking about is actually $5000 pesos here, which is cheap but also the money u earn in two days of work with the minimum salary (16 hours), saying this just in case there's ppl saying "its just 15 dollars lmao its nothing".

thx for reading.

[image: pic of the part without fan]

Comment: According to Tweakers that GPU is 10 years old and uses 130W, so passive cooling is not really doable and you will be better off searching for a GTX 950 (probably)

Comment: i also have an open case, would it be still be bad? i do have a spare fan i could put close to it and also, cheapest gtx 950 is 5x more expensive than this

Comment: If you want to upgrade, don't spend 2 days of salary on a bad upgrade from 10 years ago. And depending on the shape of the heatsink, you may be able to get away with putting a fan on it (with ducktape) but it's still probably gonna be hot.

Comment: true true, i'll just be patient